# Close jQuery menu on mouseLeave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a small drop-down container which appears when You hover on top of a menu item. When I hover on top of the menu item (e.g. Tools) the dropdown appears, I can move my mouse inside, but when the cursor leaves the dropdown menu, it does not go away. How am I able to achieve this?

I only managed to make it dissapear when you click somewhere outside of it.

Here is a [**Fiddle.**](https://jsfiddle.net/9rwycrsy/2/)

```
var dropdown = $('.nav-dropdown');

dropdown.hide();

$('#dropdownToggle').hover(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  dropdown.show(200);
  dropdown.addClass('active');

  $(window).click(function() {
    dropdown.slideUp();
  });

  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

---

> **SOLUTION** by [**anima_incognita**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4259093/anima-incognita):

```
var dropdown = $('.nav-dropdown');

dropdown.hide();

$('#dropdownToggle').hover(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  dropdown.show(200);
  dropdown.addClass('active');

  $(window).click(function() {
    dropdown.slideUp();
  });

  $(".nav-dropdown").on('mouseleave',function(){
      dropdown.slideUp();
  });

  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to end of your code:

```
$(".nav-dropdown").on('mouseleave',function(){
    dropdown.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

here is edit in your code worked fine with me...added methods

```
var dropdown = $('.nav-dropdown');

dropdown.hide();

$('#dropdownToggle').mouseenter(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  dropdown.show(200);
  dropdown.addClass('active');

  $(window).click(function() {
    dropdown.slideUp();
  });

$('#dropdownToggle').mouseleave(function(e) {
dropdown.slideUp();
});
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Now there is no way to enter the link container. @anima_incognita's answer fits my solution. Thank You for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Update your JS:

```js
var dropdown = $('.nav-dropdown');

dropdown.hide();

$('#dropdownToggle').hover(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  dropdown.show(200);
  dropdown.addClass('active');

  $(window).click(function() {
    dropdown.slideUp();
  });

  e.stopPropagation();
});

$(".nav-dropdown").on('mouseleave', function() {
  dropdown.slideUp('fast');
});
```

```css
.nav-list {
  .nav-list-item {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 2rem;
    background: tomato;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .nav-dropdown {
      position: absolute;
      background: turquoise;
      padding: 2rem;
      li {
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-list">

  <li class="nav-list-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link services">Services</a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-list-item dropdown-wrapper">
    <a href="#" id="dropdownToggle" class="nav-link tools">Tools
        </a>
    <!-- dropdown -->
    <ul class="nav-dropdown active" style="display: block;">

      <li class="nav-dropdown-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-dropdown-item-link">Buyer Cost Sheet</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-dropdown-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-dropdown-item-link">Seller Net Sheet</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-dropdown-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-dropdown-item-link">Mortage Calculator</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-dropdown-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-dropdown-item-link">Title Fees</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-dropdown-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-dropdown-item-link">Refi Calculator</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-dropdown-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-dropdown-item-link">Real Estate Forms</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-list-item">
    <a href="buyersandsellers.html" class="nav-link buy-sale">Buyers &amp; Sellers</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the hover function, the hover function specifies two function to trigger mouseenter and mouseleave event

You have defined only the mouseenter function and not defined the mouseleave function. So below is the updated JS code:

```
$('#dropdownToggle').hover(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 dropdown.show(200);
 dropdown.addClass('active');
 e.stopPropagation();
}, function(e){
e.preventDefault();
dropdown.slideUp();;
dropdown.removeClass('active');
});
```